# Specflow skips test after execution with error: Error while unpacking executor:

Tags: visual-studio-2017, specflow, specrun

after updating SpecflowRunner to 3.5.8 and re-installing the Specflow Package 2017.2.1 my tests cannot be executed and are skipped instead. When I open the log file I find this Error message:

**Error while unpacking executor: System.TypeLoadException: The method "Initialize" in type "TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestAssemblyExecutor" of the assembly "TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" is not implemented.**

(Sorry, I had to translate the message)

A friend of mine has the same versions, but everything runs smoothly. We both use Visual Studio 2017.
Did I miss something, a cache that has to be cleared or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably some old leftover files from before the update in your `obj` and `bin` folder.

- Close Visual Studio
- delete the folders
- start Visual Studio
- Rebuild Solution

After that, you should be able to execute your tests again.